# Note: myline.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Tags: java, compiler-errors

***This is my code***

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class myline extends Applet
{
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
g.drawLine(100,10,250,150);
g.drawLine(100,150,150,150);
}
}
```

Error shown when compiling
C:\Users\Admin\Downloads>javac myline.java
Note: myline.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: 1)  Do what the error message says.  Seriously.  2) The Applet class is deprecated.  It was deprecated in Java 9 ... and in the Java 17 codebase it is now labeled for removal.  Applets are a dead technology.  It is no longer supported by modern web browsers ... apart from IE ... which EOL next year.

Comment: So, the best solution is to throw this code away, and stop using (and teaching!) applets.